# Is there a way to add a custom column when we create a many2many association in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to know 2 things
I got the following structs from a similar question.

```
// models/school.go
type School struct {
    ID                int      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name              string `gorm:"not null"`
    Accreditations    []Accreditation `gorm:"many2many:school_accreditation;"` 
}

type Accreditation struct {
    // "accreditation" table
    ID          int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name        string
    Description string
}
```

So, by default this will create a `school_accreditation` table with 2 columns:

- one will have **School's ID**
- other will have **Accreditation's ID**

My questions:

1. What is the most efficient way to add another column to the `school_accreditation` table?
2. Let's say I want to have the `Name` field of `Accreditation` in the `school_accreditation` table.
   2.1) How do I achieve this eg: `school_accreditation` will have `school_id`, `accreditation_id`, `accreditation_name`

Comment: No then split many-to-many into two OnetoMany with join table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st question,
It seems the only way of doing it by defining the `SchoolAccreditation` model & adding fields to it.
Also, it gives me more control over the relationship.
For the 2nd question, I am yet to find a way if there is any!
bost

For the 2nd,
You have to manually get the `name` from `Accreditation` & then add it to the column via the defined `SchoolAccreditation` model.